# How to bind a Socket to a Network interface

Tags: sockets, flutter

The app must connect to a socket server hosted at 192.168.0.10:35000 by an IoT device through a WiFi network it provides while having an active data connection.

The following code throws an error:

> SocketException: Connection timed out, host: 192.168.0.10, port: 35000

```
this._socket = await Socket.connect('192.168.0.10', 35000);
```

If I disable the mobile's Data connection, it connects as it should. I think that confirms that the Socket is not bound to the WiFi network.

On a native Android environment, I believe that the [`ConnectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#bindProcessToNetwork(android.net.Network)) method, or the [`Network.getSocketFactory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network#getSocketFactory()) method, would do the trick.

Is there any way to achieve this without writing native code?

Some extra information:

Running `InternetAddress.lookup()` on '192.168.0.10' gives the following:

[image]

Running `NetworkInterfaces.list()` gives the following:

[image]

Comment: A mobile device, like a phone or tablet, is usually connected either to a WiFi network or a Cellular network, but rarely both at the same time. Apparently yours is like that, which would explain why you have to turn off your Cellular connection to reach your IoT device over WiFi by default. Are you sure you are actually connected to both networks at the sam time? The APIs you mention are Java based APIs, not native NDK based APIs, so have you actually tried them yet?

Comment: Remy, thank you for the reply. I belive it doesn't matter acctually how many Network Interfaces the device has. It can have 'n', as long as I am able to choose which one to use. When I said 'native Android' it's because this is a Flutter environment, so I wasn't referring to NDK, but that might be misunderstood, I'm sorry. 

Basically, I need to achieve what this guy describes [here](https://www.cumulations.com/blogs/92/using-both-ethernet-and-wifi-interfaces-for-communication-in-androidthings), with **Flutter**.

Comment: [Flutter can access Android Java APIs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Comment: I'm aware of that naturally, but my question is: can I achieve that without having to write native code?